# Find total resistance

Tags: resistance

[image]

The book (Principles of Electric Circuits by Thomas Floyd 9th edition, International edition) says it's **1.955k Ω**.
When I calculate I get (R1 || R2) + (R3 || R4) + R5 = 3.38k Ω.

Comment: Between which two points?

Comment: What reasoning did you use when you decided to place R3 and R4 in parallel? Also why R5 in series, if R1 and R2 are in parallel?

Comment: These kinds of problems are fairly easy to attack by reducing parts of the circuit successively to Thevenin equivalents.  If you only care about the resistance, not the voltage, then you can consider all voltage sources as shorts to make things even simpler.  To walk thru a solution, we need to know which two nodes you are trying to find the effective total resistance between, as Steven already mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the total resistance is requested from the + output of the 2V supply to GND.  That gives:

(((R4 || R5) + R3) || R2) + R1 = 1.95498k

Comment: Actually, that works for either supply. If you swap the two right-hand arms of the circuit, you'll see the symmetry.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe what I was thinking... did tons of exercises like these, then suddenly today I just... went full retard...

Comment: @IQlessThan70 - Well, with an RTIQ (Room Temperature IQ) you can't help it, I guess... :-)

Comment: I'm surprised Steven didn't make a remark on the 6 significant digits... :)